# How to make a picture appear with IBAction on another page Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am wanting my image to appear on the next page when I click a button on the previous page, is this possible? I have set up the storyboards as push when the button is clicked...it goes to the page but my image is not displaying.

This is my .h code:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *Image1;


- (IBAction)Button:(id)sender;
```

and my .m

```
- (IBAction)Button:(id)sender {

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

    [_Image1 setImage:img];

}
```

I think it must be because it forgets the action once it has opened the new page, but am not sure as I though push remembered?!

Any help would be great!!
Thanks

Comment: Button is not visible means?

Comment: So sorry I mean the image does not display!

Comment: Please, name your var starting with a lowercase, same for your methods. What do you mean by "page"? Another ViewController? If yes, I guess, you'll have to look how to pass data through segues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide the segue an identifier (eg.*ShowSecondScreen*) which connects two `ViewController`

then, fire your segue from first viewController

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowSecondScreen" sender:self];
```

Make a `strong` `property` in `secondViewController` (eg. *passedImage*)

And to handle this fired segue, use

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowSecondScreen"]) {
            SecondViewController *secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
            secondViewController.passedImage = image;
        }
    }
```